# Assign numbered ID to dynamically created Element of selectable Grid by "Yair even or"

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, jquery-ui-selectable

I want to assign an ID to every Element(.grid__area) that gets created by the user. For Example: **area1**, **area2** and so on. Problem is that I can't figure out where to place it correctly.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/ONWmmq

I've  tried to locate the moment where the element gets created and via

```
.attr('id','area'+count+'')
```

to assign the new id.

```
this.DOM.scope.append( selectionArea ); // Line 242
console.log('Created!');
```

But I can't trigger `this` nor I can't place it in the area template section.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before line 242 ([demo](https://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/eEwxjq)):

```
selectionArea.attr('id','area'+count++);
```

Don't forget to include the `counter` variable in the `grid`.